# join datasets with different dimensions - how to aggregate data properly

Tags: scala, apache-spark, join, aggregate

I am working on a complex logic where I need to redistribute a quantity from one dataset to another dataset.

This questions is a continuation of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62708493/quantity-redistribution-logic-mapgroups-with-external-dataset)

In the example below I am introducing several new dimensions. After aggregating and distributing all the quantities I am expecting the same total quantity however I have some differences.

See the example below

```
package playground

import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, round, sum}

object sample3 {

  val spark = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .appName("Sample app")
    .master("local")
    .getOrCreate()

  val sc = spark.sparkContext

  final case class Owner(a: Long,
                         b: String,
                         c: Long,
                         d: Short,
                         e: String,
                         f: String,
                         o_qtty: Double)

  // notice column d is not present in Invoice
  final case class Invoice(c: Long,
                           a: Long,
                           b: String,
                           e: String,
                           f: String,
                           i_qtty: Double)

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.OFF)

    import spark.implicits._

    val ownerData = Seq(
      Owner(11, "A", 666, 2017, "x", "y", 50),
      Owner(11, "A", 222, 2018, "x", "y", 20),
      Owner(33, "C", 444, 2018, "x", "y", 20),
      Owner(33, "C", 555, 2018, "x", "y", 120),
      Owner(22, "B", 555, 2018, "x", "y", 20),
      Owner(99, "D", 888, 2018, "x", "y", 100),
      Owner(11, "A", 888, 2018, "x", "y", 100),
      Owner(11, "A", 666, 2018, "x", "y", 80),
      Owner(33, "C", 666, 2018, "x", "y", 80),
      Owner(11, "A", 444, 2018, "x", "y", 50),
    )

    val invoiceData = Seq(
      Invoice(444, 33, "C", "x", "y", 10),
      Invoice(999, 22, "B", "x", "y", 200),
      Invoice(666, 11, "A", "x", "y", 15),
      Invoice(555, 22, "B", "x", "y", 200),
      Invoice(888, 11, "A", "x", "y", 12),
    )

    val owners = spark
      .createDataset(ownerData)
      .as[Owner]
      .cache()

    val invoices = spark
      .createDataset(invoiceData)
      .as[Invoice]
      .cache()

    val p1 = owners
      .join(invoices, Seq("a", "c", "e", "f", "b"))
      .selectExpr(
        "a",
        "d",
        "b",
        "e",
        "f",
        "c",
        "IF(o_qtty-i_qtty < 0,o_qtty,o_qtty - i_qtty) AS qtty",
        "IF(o_qtty-i_qtty < 0,0,i_qtty) AS to_distribute"
      )

    val p2 = owners
      .join(invoices, Seq("a", "c", "e", "f", "b"), "left_outer")
      .filter(row => row.anyNull)
      .drop(col("i_qtty"))
      .withColumnRenamed("o_qtty", "qtty")

    val distribute = p1
      .groupBy("a", "d", "b", "e", "f")
      .agg(sum(col("to_distribute")).as("to_distribute"))

    val proportion = p2
      .groupBy("a", "d", "b", "e", "f")
      .agg(sum(col("qtty")).as("proportion"))

    val result = p2
      .join(distribute, Seq("a", "d", "b", "e", "f"))
      .join(proportion, Seq("a", "d", "b", "e", "f"))
      .withColumn(
        "qtty",
        round(
          ((col("to_distribute") / col("proportion")) * col("qtty")) + col(
            "qtty"
          ),
          2
        )
      )
      .drop("to_distribute", "proportion")
      .union(p1.drop("to_distribute"))
    result.show(false)
    result.selectExpr("SUM(qtty)").show()
    owners.selectExpr("SUM(o_qtty)").show()
    
    /*
    +---+----+---+---+---+---+-----+
    |a  |d   |b  |e  |f  |c  |qtty |
    +---+----+---+---+---+---+-----+
    |11 |2018|A  |x  |y  |222|27.71|
    |33 |2018|C  |x  |y  |555|126.0|
    |33 |2018|C  |x  |y  |666|84.0 |
    |11 |2018|A  |x  |y  |444|69.29|
    |11 |2017|A  |x  |y  |666|35.0 |
    |33 |2018|C  |x  |y  |444|10.0 |
    |22 |2018|B  |x  |y  |555|20.0 |
    |11 |2018|A  |x  |y  |888|88.0 |
    |11 |2018|A  |x  |y  |666|65.0 |
    +---+----+---+---+---+---+-----+
    
    +---------+
    |sum(qtty)|
    +---------+
    |    525.0|
    +---------+
    
    +-----------+
    |sum(o_qtty)|
    +-----------+
    |      640.0|
    +-----------+
     */
  }

}
```

Also, note that the aggregation must not produce any negative quantity.

Comment: HI @Michael, I tested your code and I think it's working properly with your data sample or I am missing something. Try ````result.selectExpr("SUM(qtty)").show()````, I get 570.

Comment: Hi @Chema thanks - I've edited the example with more columns to reflect the problem. As you can see the total quantity is different after the distribution. Also note that column "d" is not present in Invoice but it is in Owner - I guess I need to introduce some window function but I'm not sure how exactly to do so. Thanks again for your great support

Comment: has the rules for aggregation changed or they remain the same? If ````d```` is not present in Invoice, how does it compute? and finally, there are two ````A 666```` in different years, how does it compute? because ````Invoice```` doesn't have the category ````year````. I need to know those business rules.

Comment: The aggregation rule remains the same, for the case where `Owners` contains multiple years (column `d`) - the quantity "to be distributed" must be distributed according to each year quantity. It is a sort of distribution inside the distribution. Thanks

Comment: Hi @Michael,Ok I think I get it,  but in the case of ````Owner(99, "D", 888, 2018, "x", "y", 100)```` that is not present in the Invoice table, how does it compute?

Comment: It must be ignored in the redistribution and must appear as-is in the final output. It counts as an item but it is not distributed. Really looking forward to a solution :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I show the code where was necessary to do changes.

```scala
val distribute = p1
  .groupBy("a","b", "e", "f") // now we don't need to aggregate by field "d"
  .agg(sum(col("to_distribute")).as("to_distribute"))
```

```scala
val proportion = p2
  .groupBy("a","b", "e", "f") // now we don't need to aggregate by field "d"
  .agg(sum(col("qtty")).as("proportion"))
```

```scala
// Here we remove "d" from the join
// If the distribution is null(there is no data in invoices for that owner) 
// then we keep the original "qtty"
// column "d" from p2 dataframe was renamed as "year"
val result = p2
  .join(distribute, Seq("a","b", "e", "f"),"left_outer")
  .join(proportion, Seq("a","b", "e", "f"))
  .selectExpr("a","b","e","f","c","IF(ROUND( ((to_distribute/proportion) * qtty) + qtty, 2) IS NULL,qtty,ROUND( ((to_distribute/proportion) * qtty) + qtty, 2)) AS qtty","d AS year")
  .union(p1.withColumn("year",col("d")).drop("d","to_distribute"))
  .orderBy(col("b"))
```

```scala
****EXPECTED OUTPUT****
+---+---+---+---+---+-----+----+
|a  |b  |e  |f  |c  |qtty |year|
+---+---+---+---+---+-----+----+
|11 |A  |x  |y  |444|80.0 |2018|
|11 |A  |x  |y  |222|32.0 |2018|
|11 |A  |x  |y  |666|65.0 |2018|
|11 |A  |x  |y  |888|88.0 |2018|
|11 |A  |x  |y  |666|35.0 |2017|
|22 |B  |x  |y  |555|20.0 |2018|
|33 |C  |x  |y  |555|126.0|2018|
|33 |C  |x  |y  |444|10.0 |2018|
|33 |C  |x  |y  |666|84.0 |2018|
|99 |D  |x  |y  |888|100.0|2018|
+---+---+---+---+---+-----+----+



+---------+
|sum(qtty)|
+---------+
|    640.0|
+---------+

+-----------+
|sum(o_qtty)|
+-----------+
|      640.0|
+-----------+
```

Comment: Really impressive! May I ask you how you come up to this answer, did you follow some specific reasoning. Did you compute the solution in SQL first maybe?

Comment: Hi @Michael, Thanks for your comments, i really appreciate it. I could just say that I only use pencil, paper and a bit of time depending of the problem :-)